# Regarding jQuery's scrollTop. Scroll to different target (other than back to top)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop

I am currently using jQuery's .scrollTop which works perfectly for moving the user back to the top of the page. And since I really like the effect, I would like to make it possible to scroll to some asigned div or anchor point.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I do this? Can someone give me an example?
I want also to retain the scrollTop function itself.

I already checked Stackflow, but or this is not possible, or I overlooked a similar question (in that case I am sorry for posting a new question).

Here is a link to scrollTop: http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple jQuery function can achieve this:

```
function scrollTo(id){
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/cMxXM/4/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the function you gave me, however I am unable to make it work? What should I add to make it work? Unfortunately I do not have much knowledge about JS and / or PHP. :(

Comment: Thanks that explains a lot for me. I already tried to look (and understand) at the source of scrollto (http://flesler.blogspot.nl/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) however that didn't help me out a lot. Your example, however, does help me out a lot. Thank you very much!